# Tweak IE Conditional Comment with Nokogiri without converting entities

Tags: ruby, xml, xhtml, nokogiri, conditional-comments

I have an XHTML file with an [HTML5 Shiv](http://code.google.com/p/html5shiv/) in the head:

```
<!--[if lt IE 9]>
  <script src='../common/html5.js' type='text/javascript'></script>
<![endif]-->
```

Using [Nokogiri](http://nokogiri.org) I need to adjust the path in that comment, stripping off the `../`. However, any changes to the `.content` of the comment node results in XML output that converts the `>` and `<` to entities:

```
XML = <<ENDXML
<r><!--[if lt IE 9]>
  <script src='../common/html5.js' type='text/javascript'></script>
<![endif]--></r>
ENDXML

require 'nokogiri'
doc = Nokogiri.XML(XML)
comment = doc.at_xpath('//comment()')
comment.content = comment.content.sub('../','')
puts comment.to_xml
#=> <!--[if lt IE 9]&gt;
#=>   &lt;script src='common/html5.js' type='text/javascript'&gt;&lt;/script&gt;
#=> &lt;![endif]-->
```

The original source is valid XML/XHTML. How can I get Nokogiri not to convert the entities inside this comment during tweaking?

Comment: Sometimes it's ok to use regex. This is probably one of those times.

Comment: @pguardiario That's what I've currently done, on the `to_s` of the XML immediately before writing to file. The problem/annoyance is that this really should occur in the middle of conversion, at which point I only _have_ a `Nokogiri::XML::Document` upon which to operate.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [Nokogiri docs for `content=`](http://nokogiri.org/Nokogiri/XML/Node.html#method-i-content-3D) say:

> The string gets XML escaped, not interpreted as markup.

So rather than using that, you could replace the node with a new one, using [`replace`](http://nokogiri.org/Nokogiri/XML/Node.html#method-i-replace) and an explicitly created [comment node](http://nokogiri.org/Nokogiri/XML/Comment.html):

```ruby
XML = <<ENDXML
<r><!--[if lt IE 9]>
  <script src='../common/html5.js' type='text/javascript'></script>
<![endif]--></r>
ENDXML

require 'nokogiri'
doc = Nokogiri.XML(XML)
comment = doc.at_xpath('//comment()')

# this line is the new one, replacing comment.content= ...
comment.replace Nokogiri::XML::Comment.new(doc, comment.content.sub('../',''))

# note `comment` is the old comment, so to see the changes
# look at the whole document
puts doc.to_xml
```

Output is:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<r>
  <!--[if lt IE 9]>
  <script src='common/html5.js' type='text/javascript'></script>
<![endif]-->
</r>
```